# Robot Framework “multipart/form-data” REST request

Tags: rest, robotframework

**Im trying to use this form for the post body request**

------WebKitFormBoundary4POLnCIPMmfk10Cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"multi"}
------WebKitFormBoundary4POLnCIPMmfk10Cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ai.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundary4POLnCIPMmfk10Cb--

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.